# Two lists combined into 1 dropdown box

Tags: sql, list, vb6

Dear all and thank you in advance.

**Problem:**

Instead of having two dropdown boxes for list A and list B. I would like to combine the two lists (they do relate) and display them to the user as 1 list. Then split it back into two so that I can store the relevant info.

List 1

```
Machines
1. Machine x
2. Machine y
```

List 2  Test Types

```
1. Test Type ab
2. Test Type ac
3. Text Type ad.
```

so Machine 1 can do test type ab, and ac. Machine 2 can do test type ac and ad.

It will be stored under 3 different tables (not really but just think that it will). 2 tables will contain the list and the third will contain the relationship between the two lists. I.e. which items from list 1 pair up with which items from list 2 etc.

To the user it would be displayed as follows

```
Machine X - ab
Machine x - ac
Machine y - ac
Machine y - ad
```

The user would then select 1 from the list and I would then decode the two items selected.

My thought so far is to use bits (and/or) as required.

There will be three functions

```
public function joinAB(a as long, b as long) as long

end function

Public function getA(ab as long) as long

end function

public function getB(ab as long)as long 
end function
```

So just to clarify this is not to join text together, but to join/split ID's of the individual items in these two lists.

Anyone else have any other ideas. This will be done in a legacy system (VB6) which I have inherited. My VB6 coding skills are above average.

Thank you for any help/code snippets provided or general advice.

If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a and b are numeric variables as your 3 functions suggest I would use the .ItemData() property of the items in the combined list just like Mark and use division and remained to obtain the separate parts:

```
Public Function joinAB(a As Long, b As Long) As Long
  joinAB = a * 100 + b
End Function

Public Function getA(ab As Long) As Long
  getA = ab \ 100
End Function

Public Function getB(ab As Long) As Long
  getB = ab Mod 100
End Function
```

this assumes that b will never be higher than 100, and that neither a or b will be negative

If a and b are string variables then i would show the joined strings as the text int he combobox and split the selected text to get the seprate parts

```
Public Function joinAB(a As String, b As String) As String
  joinAB = a & " - " & b
End Function

Public Function getA(ab As String) As String
  getA = Left$(ab, InStr(ab, " - ") - 1)
End Function

Public Function getB(ab As String) As String
  getB = Mid$(ab, InStr(ab, " - ") + 3)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

make use of the 3rd table in which the relation is mapped , if the relation have a unique id then you can make use of that to join/split the list....

or provide us with the table structure and data...

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a few solutions to this.

The simplest is that you create a unique 32-bit integer field on your join table. This can then be embedded in the ItemData property of the VB6 ListBox.

A couple of helper functions for this are:

```
Private Sub AddListBoxItem(ByRef lst as ListBox, ByVal in_nKey As Long, ByRef in_sDisplay As String)
    With lst
        .AddItem in_sDisplay
        .ItemData(.NewIndex) = in_nKey
    End With
End Sub

Private Function GetSelectedListBoxKey(ByRef in_lst As ListBox) As Long
    With in_lst
        GetSelectedListBoxKey = .ItemData(.ListIndex)
    End With
End Function
```

As for implementing your functions, I would simply use two collection.

m_col_A_B_to_AB would be keyed by A & "_" & B to return AB. m_col_AB_to_A_B would be keyed to AB to return A and B.

Helper functions would be:

```
Private Sub AddRow(ByVal in_nA As Long, ByVal in_nB As Long, ByVal in_nAB As Long)
    Dim an(0 To 1) As Long
    an(0) = in_nA
    an(1) = in_nB
    m_col_A_B_to_AB.Add an(), CStr(in_nAB)
    m_col_AB_to_A_B.Add in_nAB, CStr(in_nA) & "_" & CStr(in_nB)
End Sub

Private Sub Get_A_B(ByVal in_nAB As Long, ByRef out_nA As Long, ByRef out_nB As Long)

    Dim vTmp As Variant
    vTmp = m_col_A_B_to_AB.Item(CStr(in_nAB))

    out_nA = vTmp(0)
    out_nB = vTmp(1)

End Sub

Private Function GetA(ByVal in_nAB As Long) As Long
    Get_A_B in_nAB, GetA, 0&
End Function

Private Function GetB(ByVal in_nAB As Long) As Long
    Get_A_B in_nAB, 0&, GetB
End Function

Private Function JoinAB(ByVal in_nA As Long, ByVal in_nB As Long) As Long

    JoinAB = m_col_AB_to_A_B.Item(CStr(in_nA) & "_" & CStr(in_nB))

End Function
```